# JS Link create a Column / read metadata of a document

Tags: javascript, document-library, jslink, file-metadata

I'm new to SharePoint and JS Link. I have to read the metadata of a document in a document library. If the document is locked for the current user, I want to create an extra column and display an image in that field (of the Column) to show that the document is locked.

So I want to know: Is it possible to create a new column and read the metadata of a document in my JavaScript? If so, how do I do that?

Or, do I have to create the Column manually in SharePoint before I can re-render the fields via JS Link?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CSR you can display existing Columns anyway you want, so there is no need to Create another Column

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-97e27fa1/sourcecode?fileId=109736&pathId=1717720622

Is an MSDN example which uses another field to indicate if a document is locked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, he is using another field for looking at the permission, but is there a way to get the "yes/no" value out of the metadata of the document ?

Comment: Sure, the ``ctx`` has all the metadata **available in the current View** With a View displayed you can check in F12 Dev Tools: ``ctx.ListData.Row[0]``

Comment: What metadata says/identifies the document is locked?

Comment: OK thanks, I will look for the ctx.ListData.Row. It has a custom property/metadata which is called "vertraulich" / "nicht vertraulich"